# relational database query

Tags: mysql, relational-database

How would i combine these queries? The 'deleted' field is a timestamp indicating when the topic was "deleted". The topic doesn't really get deleted. I just no not to display it if it has an actual timestamp.

```
$topics = "SELECT id FROM topics WHERE deleted = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'";

$comments = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE topic_id IN($topics)";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this solution:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM comments a
INNER JOIN topics b ON 
    a.topic_id = b.id AND 
    b.deleted = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```